# Converting std::vector from BYTE to int

Tags: vector, visual-c++

Code:

```
using ColumnIndexVector = std::vector<int>;
using ByteVector = std::vector<BYTE>;

void CCreateReportDlg::GetColumnIndexesToExclude()
{
    const CString strSection = theApp.GetActiveScheduleSection(_T("Options"));

    ByteVector vData = theApp.GetProfileVector(strSection, _T("AssignStatesEx"));

    ColumnIndexVector vTemp(vData.begin(), vData.end()); // This converts BYTE to int
    m_vColumnIndexesToExclude = vTemp;

}
```

Is there any way to avoid the requirement for `vTemp` without manually iterating `vData` and casting from `BYTE` to `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `assign()`. IDK if you need to use `clear()` as well, but probably not. Just step through the runtime code the first time to know.

```
m_vColumnIndexesToExclude.assign(vData.begin(), vData.end());
```

Here's a test program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using ColumnIndexVector = std::vector<int>;
using ByteVector = std::vector<BYTE>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    
    ByteVector bytes = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
    
    ColumnIndexVector colVector;
    
    for ( auto _val: bytes)
    {
        cout << _val << endl;
    }
    
    colVector.assign(bytes.begin(), bytes.end());
    for ( auto _val : colVector)
    {
        cout << _val << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, for sure don't have to call .clear(). I initialized int vector with values, and after `assign()`, those values were no longer in vector.